# make label update on file directory change (visual basic)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, automation, openfiledialog

When I use an OpenFileDialog, and select a file and click open etc, etc...

I want a label on the same form to automatically update with the directory path. At the moment I have this working, However the label updates on click, not automatically on the directory change.

CODE:

```
Private Sub Label4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label4.Click

    Label4.Text = OpenFileDialog2.FileName

End Sub
```

Cna I change the "Label4_Click" to something else for an auto update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you displaying the OpenFileDialog?  You need to update the Label from there!...

Something like:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If OpenFileDialog2.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Label4.Text = OpenFileDialog2.FileName
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: hahahaha thanks mate, that was pretty obvious wasn't it! can't believe i didn't think of this.